# Android: how to launch an activity from optionmenu?

Tags: android, android-intent, optionmenu

I've read a couple of questions in the forum and try it on my code. But this functionality in my app is not working yet.

I have two activities. The first one is MapsActivity.java. It contains a google map where I added some markers (created with Google Maps Android APIs). The second one is supernatural.java.
I'm already able to move from the first activity to the second one.
In the second activity I inserted an option menu at the bottom, and I'd like to start different activities for each option.
The first option is an icon that, when clicked, should bring me back to the MapsActivity.java
For reasons I don't understand, when I click the icon, nothing  happens.

Here's my code I think is relevant to the question:

AndroidManifest file where I have declared my two activities

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mgiannone.dublinfarmersmarket" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".supernatural"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_supernatural" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

The menu .xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.mgiannone.dublinfarmersmarket.supernatural">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"   android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/map"
    android:title="@string/iconMap"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_maps_place"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/review"
    android:title="@string/iconReview"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_question_answer"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

The supenatural.java class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;


public class supernatural extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_supernatural);

    //declare a Toolabr and inflate it
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
    myToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_supernatural);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_supernatural, menu);
    return true;
    }


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    //handling the options selected
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.map:
            // Map option clicked.
            Intent intentMap = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intentMap);
            return true;
        case R.id.review:
            // Review option clicked.
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
}
```

The only thing I can think of at the moment is some sort of issue with the MapsActivity.java file. Should I use a particular method to call this kind of Activity created using Google Maps Android APIs?
For completeness I'm adding also the code of MapsActivity.java class:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap myMap) {
    // Move the camera to Dublin
    myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(53.345350459503486, -6.272483224804773), 12));

    //Set the markers on the map
    Marker greenDoor = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(53.33783832056784, -6.277552599842919))    //set latitude and longitude
            .title("The Green Door")                                        //set a title for the marker
            .snippet("18 Newmarket, Dublin 8")                              //set additional text for the marker once it is touched by the user
            .icon((BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.farmstand)))  //change the default icon to a customized one imported in 'drawable'
    );

    Marker supernaturalFM = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(53.342849229144676, -6.242303008969202))
                    .title("Supernatural")
                    .snippet("114 - 116 Pearse Street, Dublin 2")
                    .icon((BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.farmstand)))
    );



    myMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(
            new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker supernaturalFM){
                    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,supernatural.class);
                    startActivity(nextScreen);
                }
            }
    );

};
```

Comment: Have you set a break point on the switch statement? Does it reach the correct case?

Comment: No I haven't added a break point. But if I add it to both cases Android Studio marks the first one in red, says 'Unreachable statement' and the app does not compile.

Comment: I was referring to break point using the debugger, not a break to the case statement. Use the debugger to verify the code is following the path you expect.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the advice. I'll do this as soon as I can and I'll post an update.

Comment: Ok. I've found the problem. It was in the .xml menu file. The `android:onClick="onOptionsItemSelected` was not implemented. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in the switch the break point: insert `break`; after `return true;` in all cases

If you don't use `break`, the action called will be the last

Comment: I get an 'Unreacheble statement' on the first break and app won't compile

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use break at the end of every case, and you couls use:

```
                Intent act = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(act);
```

but, if you want to receive data from the second activity, you should use startActivityForResult() in the first activity, so you have a returning value

**UPDATE:**
this is the structure basic of this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.my_id)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    if (id == R.id.second_id)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "you press a button!, success ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent act = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(act);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: The break gives me an 'Unreachable statement' error and app does not compile

Comment: print a toast instead, if toast is not showed couls be your tag

Comment: I tried with `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.map) {
            Intent intentMap = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            return true;
        }else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }`  It compiles but, again, nothing happens when I click on the icon

Comment: check my update, if toast is not visible, your problem is that you have selected the wrong id

Comment: Toast is not visible. So, in the xml file I have `android:id="@+id/map"` and in the java file I have `case R.id.map:`. Isn't that the same id?

Comment: I finally found your problem, You are referencing in the function the id's from layout, is the problem, you have to reference id's from menu folder you have this menu:  R.menu.menu_supernatural, so you only must to refer to id's in this xml and not in layout

Comment: Actually I was already referencing to the ids from the menu_supernatural.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely on the right track but you need to correct a small mistake.

Just use `break` in the individual `case`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.map:
                // Map option clicked.
                Intent intentMap = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
                this.startActivity(intentMap);
                break;
            case R.id.review:
                // Review option clicked.
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this code. Unfortunately, I got an 'Unreachable statement' error at the first break and the app does not compile at all.

Comment: Yes its because of the return statement. Just remove them and it will compile fine.

Comment: I removed both the brake. It gives me a missing return of the switch statement. I added it at the end but nothing happens. Also, I think the return statement should be important to let the app now that the event has been handled. I followed [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu)

Comment: Sorry, I meant I removed both the return.

Comment: I have updated my code. This should definitely work for you.